# How to insert value into one cell mysql database according to which page the user is at?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql-update

I have a system set up that will display certain pages. I have the paignation set up already. In each page, I want to have 5 radio buttons, each named as "Definitely No", "No", "Second look", "Yes", "Definitely Yes". When the user clicks one of the radio button, php should insert one value (1-5) to a column called "viewed"  and a row according to the current page variable ($currentpage). The paignation and each page's code is here:

```
<?php
// database connection info
require_once "connect_database_viewer.php";

$table = 'JOBARXXX20140709';

// find out how many rows are in the table 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table";
$result = $db_server->query($sql) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];

// find out total pages
$totalpages = $numrows;

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
    // cast var as int
    $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
    // default page num
    $currentpage = 1;

} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
    // set current page to last page
    $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
    // set current page to first page
    $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

$query  = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$result = $db_server->query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $db_server->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

$result->data_seek($currentpage);
echo $currentpage;
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

$asin = $row[2];

echo $asin;
echo file_get_contents("http://www.amazon.com//dp/$asin/?ie=UTF8");
echo <<<_END
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://camelcamelcamel.com/product/$asin" width="1200" height="2300" align="middle"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="insert.php">
        <input type="radio" name="result" value="1">Definitely No<hr>
        <input type="radio" name="result" value="2">No<hr>
        <input type="radio" name="result" value="3">Second Look<hr>
        <input type="radio" name="result" value="4">Yes<hr>
        <input type="radio" name="result" value="5">Definitely Yes<hr>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
_END;

echo $currentpage;

/******  build the pagination links ******/
// range of num links to show
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
    // show << link to go back to page 1
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
    // get previous page num
    $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
    // show < link to go back to 1 page
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
    // if it's a valid page number...
    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
        // if we're on current page...
        if ($x == $currentpage) {
            // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
            echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
            // if not current page...
        } else {
            // make it a link
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
        } // end else
    } // end if
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
    // get next page
    $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
    // echo forward link for lastpage
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/
```

How should I write the insert.php? This is a little insert code I wrote but I don't think it is working out.

```
if(isset($_POST['result']) && !empty($_POST['result'])){
    $radioContent= $_POST['result'];

    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET viewed='1' WHERE name='$currentpage'";
    }
    else{
        error_log($mysqli->error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. If you want to use the $_POST array, make sure to set your form method to post. `<form action="insert.php" method="post">` The form element defaults to using GET.
2. `$table` and `$currentpage` will not be set in insert.php. You will have to send this information with your post. This can be done by making hidden inputs. `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $currentpage ?>" name="currentpage" />`. Now these variables will be accessible in the $_POST array. (`$_POST['currentpage']`)
3. ALWAYS escape any data being used for SQL queries. Including the hidden values made in #2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
4. You need to actually send the query to the database. As it is, you're only setting up the query string.